# mongo find function mismatch

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Mongo version : `3.2.8`

My sample json is as below

[image]

My query to fetch `name` equal to `apple` doesn't work.

```
db.collection.find( { "products.foods.name": "apple" } )
```

Instead it fetches all the records, strange?

Neither does the $eq, $lt or $gt work. They result with the entire data.

```
db.aggregation.find( { "products.foods.min_price": {$eq:10} } )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As others already told you, matching a part of the document returns the complete document unless you take special measures like using the aggregation framework. However, as you seem to regard the food-entries as single records and expect them to be returned individually from that query, my guess is that you have a rather fundamental misunderstanding regarding documents in mongo. The JSON you posted looks like one document to hold it all, which about equals wrtiting all your data in a single row in a relational database. Consider a separate collection for food and individual docs per entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to n `$unwind` both the arrays.

```
db.foods.aggregate([   
    { $unwind : "$products" },
    { $unwind : "$products.foods" },
    { $match  : { "products.foods.min_price": 10        }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

If your entire document is in an _id, then if the query matches `db.collection.find( { "products.foods.name": "apple" } )` even though it is a document in foods array the entire document will be displayed, so that you are getting other fruits as well.

To Solve this first use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the aggregation pipeline to break the foods array into individual documents and then use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

Please refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459064/how-to-get-all-negative-value-document-for-particular-user-using-express-js-with/40462070#40462070), It is a similar question and I have answered the steps in detail in that post.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match: {'products.foods.name': 'apple'}}])
```

Taken from [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

You can try other examples from that post.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:`db.Exercise.aggregate([
    {$match: {'products.foods.min_price': 10}}])`